# T-test or regression?

Tags: regression, t-test

I have the following kind of data

```
id    age    x
1     22     2.1
2     25     2.3
3     50     1.3
```

where $x$ is some measurement variable. I would like to show that there is linear relationship between $x$ and age. I would not like to do predictions.

Should I divide the samples into groups such as "young" and "old" and do a t-test or do a regression analysis? The ages are not evenly distributed. I have many subjects in the age range 20-40 (~75% of data), and only few in the age range 40-60 (~25% of data).

Could I bin the data if I do a regression analysis? E.g. take the mean age for intervals of 5 years, and the fit the line.

Comment: Your first step would be to explore the data. Visualize it. `library(ggplot2); ggplot(data, aes(x = age, y = x) + theme_bw() + geom_point()`. Construct the model (use `lm` or `glm`) and check for assumptions.

Comment: I have looked at the data. R squared would be 0.25. If I bin the data with 5 year intervals, R squared would be 0.9. I don't know if it is acceptable to do that. The t-test would also give a significant result. There's no major outliers. I'd just like to pick a test that is most convincing.

Comment: I think you should pick the test that will correctly answer your question.

Comment: You should not normally dichotomize (or otherwise group) continuous data. When you say you binned it, did you also average $x$, or was it only the ages that were grouped?

Comment: Yes, I averaged $x$. So, I guess I go with the regression without binning.

Answer (score 0):

To show that there is a linear relationship between 2 variables you can estimate the [Pearson's correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient). Doing regression is also on the table since in this way you will be able to check the assumptions (normality of the residuals) and retrieve the actual parameters of the relationship.